# How do I also include the document ID in the document, in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

---

I would also like to add a `docId` property in the document, and the value would be the document's ID. `MCFF1PRtqamB7u...` in the example from the screenshot above.

Comment: You could do this in code, but I'd recommend against it. It pretty much sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now: what are you trying to accomplish by duplicating this precise data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm currently using `vuefire` to retrieve the "portfolios" collection, however the objects in the array does not include the document id. I'm populating a list on the UI, when the list item is clicked, I would like to pass the document ID as a parameter.

Comment: As far as I can see the ID should be available in `document.id` (with `document` being whatever variable name you use in `v-for`). See for an example: https://medium.com/vue-mastery/full-stack-vue-js-with-firestore-62e2fe2ec1f3#31b6 or it could be `document['.key']`, since that is where the library adds it: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/ef17a118294f9db8a0ea3dbcde5a01a9e2d7db38/src/vuefire.js#L58